# Magento 2 - Admin Breaks Frequently if we do not clear the cache for longer time

Tags: magento2, varnish, redis

I am getting a very strange issue on my live site. If we do not clear the cache for longer time such as 2 to 3 days, any admin page gets broken.

After clearing the cache it resolves issue but it is too frequent.

Have anyone faced this kind of issue?

Varnish and Redis are installed in my site. Does any of these creates the issue?[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Both are the Server Level Cache:**

When you are using 2 server cache at one time, It may generate conflict at some place. And in your Case it is **Generating problem at your Back-end (Admin Page)**

Kindly please Enable only one Server Cache. From my Point of View Varnish Cache(HTTP Reverse Proxy) have better Performance.

Also you can use one Browser Level cache Plugin for better Performance.

Comment: Hi @oscprofessionals, thanks for your quick answer. But at the server level, we are using only Varnish. Redis has been used just for session.

Comment: Then, Please cross verify configuration of Varnish as your server cache will impact into this activity or possibly show us some screens.